# Bootstrap grid row spacing cna I use utility classes?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using the grid layout
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

For a row, can any of the spacing utility classes be used?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

eg.  Something like this?  Dont see that as an option mentioned anywhere.

```
<div class="row mb-5">
```

So what Im doing is to use my own modifier.  This achieves the desired effect, which is to reduce the spacing between rows.  Is there a way to use the utility classes for spacing with a row however?

```
<div class="row marginRow">

.marginRow {
    margin-bottom:-45px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid. You can use Bootstrap classes like margin `mb-5`, `mb-n5` or you can create custom class.

Note that there is no spacing between rows by default.

Here you have a demo:

```css
.row{height:50px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--NO SPACING-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row border border-danger"></div>
  <div class="row border border-success"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<!--Margin bottom-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-3 border border-danger"></div>
  <div class="row border border-success"></div>
</div>

<hr>

<!--Negative margin bottom-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-n3 border border-danger"></div>
  <div class="row border border-success"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, i found the culprit that was causing what "seemed" like the rows having space between them, was actually the columns I had defined within the row had margin defined at the bottom.  It just appeared that it was the row. Using the dev console / debugger /inspector helps find these things.